# How to determine runtime environment in Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I determine programatically in Access VBA code whether the code is executing in the Access runtime or in a full copy of Access?

The reason being that `On Error` handling is useful when using the Access Runtime but prevents debugging in full Microsoft Access.

Comment: *"`On Error` handling ... prevents debugging in full Microsoft Access"*  During development, you can set Error Trapping to "Break on All Errors".  That option setting will trigger break mode even when you have an `On Error` in effect.  You can find that option from the VB Editor's main menu: Tools->Options, then select the General tab from the Options dialog.

Comment: @HansUp Brilliant, I'll give that a go. Erm where does that leave this question though? Your comment is valuable to other readers but the question is wrong. If I reword the question can you promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: Hi, Caltor. I didn't intend that suggestion as an answer for your question; and it's not.  Whether or not you decide to break on all errors, I suspect an answer for "how to determine runtime environment" could still be useful.  So I'd like to see *that* question answered.  Although I'm pleased my suggestion pointed you to something you find useful, my preference is to leave the question as is and see what turns up.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp fair enough. Your comment means I no longer NEED an answer to the question but it would be interesting to see any answers to it.

Answer (score 5):

According to one of the replies in the thread [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_xp-access/how-to-determine-if-i-am-running-full-access-or/1cc99a5b-93d2-4a64-823e-b892843e15f2?msgId=f2980441-d956-48f2-9424-8908098cf7ad), testing the value of

```
SysCmd(acSysCmdRuntime)
```

in VBA code should tell you whether or not the code is running in an Access Runtime environment.